# How to find first date after given date in a sorted column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two columns of sorted dates in Excel. Given a date in column 1, how do I find the first date in column 2 *after* the given date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `INDEX` and `MATCH`. I'm assuming your date columns are sorted from oldest to newest. To find the first date after `A2` in `B2:B30`, use the following formula.

```
=INDEX(B2:B30,MATCH(A2,B2:B30,1)+1)
```

The key is that `MATCH(A2,B2:B30,1)` will return the index of the most recent date in `B2:B30` that matches or is before the date in `A2`. Since your dates are sorted, the next date in the list will occur after the date in `A2`, so adding 1 to this index will give you what you want.

Comment: what would I add to that formula to get the value in column C of the row where B matches A2?

Comment: @TrevorNewhook Just change the first argument of the `INDEX` function to `C2:C30`.